# COPY command and newline error

Tags: postgresql

I have my simple CSV file, delimited by commas and no strange character, and when trying to do a \COPY table FROM '/srv/www/.../CSV.csv' WITH DELIMITER ','  I get the error

```
 ERROR:  literal newline found in data
 HINT:  Use "\n" to represent newline.
```

Its not the first time I execute a COPY and it never happened to me. I exported the CSV from excel to Notepad and saved here as CSV (I know some programs add extra info, but AFAIK notepad does not)

Comment: Try exporting directly from Excel to csv.

Comment: My guess would be that some cell in spreadsheet contains newline (e.g. someone entered `test [ALT+Enter] test`. You can try testing your data in Excel using something like `FIND(CHAR(10),a1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import CSV, you must specify `FORMAT CSV`. A literal newline is not legal in PostgreSQL's default delimited input.

```
 \COPY table FROM '/srv/www/.../CSV.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',');
```