# Postgres literal carriage return error on Linux

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, pgadmin

**Specs**:
Linux Mint 18.x
Posgres 10.x
Pgadmin3

I've tried loading in a TSV into postgres but keep getting a literal carriage return error. In the file, "\N" is used to denote NULL.

I've tried with both `\copy` and using the import dialogue in pgadmin3. In pgadmin3 I've tried to leave out the file formating, and also tried setting it to UTF8 . Error is still persisting.

*initial command used:*

```
\copy table FROM PROGRAM 'tail -n +2 /home/super/Downloads/folder/myfile.tsv'

ERROR; literal carriage return found in data
HINT: use "\r" to represent carriage return.
```

I've been using sed to create different versions of the file that replace what I believe could be causing the error:

```
sed 's/\n/\r/g myfile.tsv > newfile1.tsv'
sed 's/\\n/\r/g myfile.tsv > newfile2.tsv'
sed 's/\\n//g myfile.tsv > newfile3.tsv'
```

I also tried the following (non chronologically)

```
sed 's/\r\n/\r/g' new.tsv

sed 's/\\N/NULL/g' new.tsv

sed 's/\\//' 

sed 's/\\N/\r/' 

sed -n 's/\n/\r/' 

sed -n 's/\\n/\r/' 

sed 's/\N/\r/' 

sed 's/\\N/NULL/' 

sed 's/\N/NULL/' 

sed 's/\r//' 

sed 's/\N/NULL/' 

sed 's/\\N/NULL/' 

sed 's/\\//' 

sed 's/\N/\r/g' new.tsv

sed 's/\N/NULL/g' new.tsv

sed 's/\N/NULL/g' new.tsv
```

And none of these have worked. When I view with LibreOffice's preview dialogue it appears to scroll through the contents and format them as a table just fine.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315121/solving-error-literal-newline-found-in-data-in-postgres) question on a literal newline error and [this question about using copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885132/copy-command-and-newline-error).

I didn't understand what was meant about the wrong 'byte' being inserted.

Preview of data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvOTz.jpg
[image: broken tsv]

UPDATE: ran `sed 's/\r/CR was here/g' myfile.tsv | grep 'CR was here'` and it returned two results

Comment: Is there any result of `sed 's/\r/CR was here/g' myfile.tsv | grep 'CR was here'` ? Also provide your actual `copy` command.

Comment: The file was produced each time without error using sed. I didn't use `grep` to search. Is there a different syntax for carriage return that I'm missing?

I was using client side `\copy`, I'll update the post.

Comment: @Abelisto the grep command returned two results with the replacement text 'CR was here' adjacent to a "\"  
eg: MYENTRY*CR was here*\

Comment: Ok, there is relatively simple way to reproduce the error: `echo -e 'aaa\nbbb\rccc' > foo.tsv ; psql -c 'create table foo(x text)' -c '\copy foo from foo.tsv' -c 'drop table foo;'` (be careful if you already have valuable `foo` table in your DB) Lets try to find how to fix it...

Comment: @Abelisto Is there dumbed down documentation I could read on how to fix it? And to understand why I'm getting this error?

Just reading your comment I see that the string is being read in with special characters--as opposed to just reading 'backslash n' it's reading in newline and same for carriage return. 

Would I have to add a slash to escape those?
something like . . . `sed 's/\r/\\r/g` ?

Comment: `echo -e 'aaa\nbbb\rccc' > foo.tsv ; sed -i 's/\r/\\r/g' foo.tsv ; psql -c 'create table foo(x text)' -c "\copy foo from foo.tsv" -c 'table foo' -c 'drop table foo;'` fixed the error. I have no ideas why `\r` sequence does not translated to CR by `copy` command as mentioned in the documentation. But it is yet another question.

Comment: Do not confuse `\N` and `\n`

Answer (score 1):

This is solved by using:
`sed 's/\r//\\r/g' myfile.tsv > myfile_copy.tsv`

It needs to be escaped twice apparently.

@Abelisto pointed out the error occuring in this comment:

> Ok, there is relatively simple way to reproduce the error: `echo -e
>   'aaa\nbbb\rccc' > foo.tsv ; psql -c 'create table foo(x text)' -c
>   '\copy foo from foo.tsv' -c 'drop table foo;'` (be careful if you
>   already have valuable foo table in your DB) Lets try to find how to
>   fix it...

Also helpful:

> `echo -e 'aaa\nbbb\rccc' > foo.tsv ; sed -i 's/\r/\\r/g' foo.tsv ;`
>   `psql -c 'create table foo(x text)' -c "\copy foo from foo.tsv" -c`
>   `'table foo' -c 'drop table foo;'` fixed the error. I have no ideas why
>   \r sequence does not translated to CR by copy command as mentioned in
>   the documentation. But it is yet another question. – Abelisto